# Azure Service Bus Topics Multiple subscribers

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am new to Azure Service Bus and would like to know if I can multiple subscribers to a queue or topic?  In rabbit MQ I can have multiple subscribers to 1 publisher.

What I am trying to do is, I am using CQRS and when certain commands come into the system when the event is handled I want to push them into a message queue.

I want 2 subscribers to be able to get the messages from that queue, one for me to process internally.  another one for process and send externally.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I am new to Azure Service Bus and would like to know if I can multiple
>   subscribers to a queue or topic?

Yes. This is possible with Azure Service Bus Topics. There can be multiple subscribers to a message sent to a topic. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions):

> In contrast to queues, in which each message is processed by a single
>   consumer, topics and subscriptions provide a one-to-many form of
>   communication, in a publish/subscribe pattern. Useful for scaling to
>   very large numbers of recipients, each published message is made
>   available to each subscription registered with the topic. Messages are
>   sent to a topic and delivered to one or more associated subscriptions,
>   depending on filter rules that can be set on a per-subscription basis.

The way it works is that you create a topic and then create multiple subscriptions in that topic. In each subscription, you can define message filtering rules. When a message is sent to a topic, Azure Service Bus matches that message against the filtering rules in each subscription and if a matching rule is found, then the message is sent to that subscription.

Comment: Does this mean that the message won't be removed until both subscribers do their thing?  Or does the first subscriber than gets to it win?  Thanks!

Comment: The messages stay in the sevice bus until all registered subscribes receive the message or the defined settings (how long message stay in the bus, max size of message etc) exceed.

Comment: A topic subscription resembles a virtual queue that receives copies of the messages that are sent to the topic.

Comment: Does each subscriber need it's own Subscription? or can they share the Subscription. If they share a subscription Do they both get to process the message or just one of them? If they share the subscription but have different filters do they each handle only the messages that are allowed by the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add something to the discussion: from the following article it seems that each listener would have to create a different subscriber in azure before listening to the same topic. Basically  a topic will have multiple subscribers (every subscription with a single listener) and so the service bus will know exactly how many subscribers will need to listen to the message before it can be completed.

https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-difference-between-azure-service-bus-queues-and-topics-comparison-azure-servicebus-queue-vs-topic-4cc97770b65